# monacaでのビルド時のエラー(Androidアプリのデバックビルド)

Tags: monaca

monacaでのAndroidアプリのビルド(デバックビルド)で下記のエラーが表示されます。
なんでビルドできないのか皆目見当がつかないのですが、
どのあたりを確認すればよいかなどをご教示いただけないでしょうか。
ちなみにデバッガーのビルドは正常終了します。

```
Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/55d97e4afd17346d32a7db18
Downloading project
Download complete
Running for 4.1
Installing &quot;mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca&quot; for android
cordova version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/55d97e4afd17346d32a7db18/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.splashscreen&quot; for android
Installing &quot;mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend&quot; for android
cordova version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/55d97e4afd17346d32a7db18/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.
Updated local.properties
No project name specified, using project folder name &apos;google-play-services_lib&apos;.
If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
Added file /private/tmp/monaca/55d97e4afd17346d32a7db18/android/skeleton/platforms/android/mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend/google-play-services_lib/build.xml
Added file /private/tmp/monaca/55d97e4afd17346d32a7db18/android/skeleton/platforms/android/mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend/google-play-services_lib/proguard-project.txt
Installing &quot;mobi.monaca.appccloud.appCCloudPlugin&quot; for android
cordova version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/55d97e4afd17346d32a7db18/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.
Fetching plugin &quot;android.support.v4&quot; via plugin registry
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/android.support.v4
npm http 304 http://registry.cordova.io/android.support.v4
cordova version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/55d97e4afd17346d32a7db18/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.
Installing &quot;android.support.v4&quot; for android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install &apos;android.support.v4&apos;:Error: Uh oh!
&quot;/private/tmp/monaca/55d97e4afd17346d32a7db18/android/skeleton/platforms/android/libs/android-support-v4.jar&quot; already exists!
    at Object.module.exports.common.copyNewFile (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/common.js:70:19)
    at module.exports.source-file.install (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/android.js:51:20)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:72:25)
    at handleInstall (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:591:20)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:340:28
    at _fulfilled (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
Failed to install &apos;mobi.monaca.appccloud.appCCloudPlugin&apos;:Error: Uh oh!
&quot;/private/tmp/monaca/55d97e4afd17346d32a7db18/android/skeleton/platforms/android/libs/android-support-v4.jar&quot; already exists!
    at Object.module.exports.common.copyNewFile (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/common.js:70:19)
    at module.exports.source-file.install (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/android.js:51:20)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:72:25)
    at handleInstall (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:591:20)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:340:28
    at _fulfilled (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
Error: Uh oh!
&quot;/private/tmp/monaca/55d97e4afd17346d32a7db18/android/skeleton/platforms/android/libs/android-support-v4.jar&quot; already exists!
    at Object.module.exports.common.copyNewFile (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/common.js:70:19)
    at module.exports.source-file.install (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/android.js:51:20)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:72:25)
    at handleInstall (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:591:20)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:340:28
    at _fulfilled (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
Build error: Error building project source code
```

Comment: `android-support-v4.jar`を使っているライブラリが複数あるのが原因でしょうか。リビジョンが違うサポートライブラリが混在するとビルドエラーになることはありますが…。

Comment: 「Cordovaプラグインの管理」でappCCloudを外したらビルドができるようになりました。
quesera2さんの仰るようにプラグインが悪さをしていたのでしょうかね？
コメントありがとうございました。